# Significant terms buckets always empty

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a collection of posts with their tags imported into Elasticsearch. The indexes are:

- language - type: keyword
- tags (array) - type: keyword
- created_at - type: date

Single document looks like that:

```
{ "language": "en", "tags": ["foo", "bar"], created_at: "..." }
```

I'm trying to get the significant terms query on my data set using:

```
GET _search
{
  "aggregations": {
    "significant_tags": {
      "significant_terms": { 
        "field": "tags"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the results bucket are always empty:

```
{
  "took": 22,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 6,
    "successful": 6,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "significant_tags": {
      "doc_count": 2945,
      "bg_count": 2945,
      "buckets": []
    }
  }
}
```

I can confirm the data is properly imported as i'm able to any other aggregation on this dataset and it works fine. Just the significant terms don't want to cooperate. Any ideas on what am i possibly doing wrong in here?

- Elasticsearch 6.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Significant terms needs a foreground query or aggregation for it to calculate difference in term frequencies and produce statistically significant results. So you will need to add a initial query then your aggregation. See the doc for details https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html

Comment: you're right. I completely misunderstood how it works but now it's fine. Thank you!